# Why reloadData is showing error for my tableView inside ViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView inside the view controller, however reloadData is not working for the tableView. Xcode shows error thread1: exc_bad_instruction. I tried to assign reloadData to other methods but the result is same? How can i fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pxEV.png)

Comment: Look at the little circles to the left of your outlets. Notice the one for the table view isn't filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlet `myTableView` did not connect to a TableView in Storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much!! So simple and so dumb question. My apologies